# Only JPanel is visible without JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to create a simple GUI in Java where I would have a JFrame and a JPanel in it with purpose to enter some images which would be later saved.

This is my code, I don't understand why only the JPanel is visible, but the JFrame cannot be seen.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class editorPTnets{


    public editorPTnets() {


        JFrame f = new JFrame("Simple GUI");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500, 600);
        f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);
        f.add(new panel1());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
}

    public class panel1 extends JPanel {
        public panel1(){
            super();
            setBackground(Color.blue);
    }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            return new Dimension(400, 200);
        }
}



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new editorPTnets();
}
```

}

I can see only a blue window which is the color for the JPanel. The yellow JFrame is not visible.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: A JFrame (its contentPane actually) uses BorderLayout by default, and so your JPanel which is being added in a default fashion will fill it completely. Read the [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: I went through the link for the BorderLayout and I managed to fix it, I will consider the other tutorials too. Thanks.

Comment: ................y/w